# If `< file` works, why doesn't `< tail file` do the same?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to feed just the latter half of a text file to a while loop, and I know I can do it in steps by creating a secondary file with the lines of interest, but I am interested to learn how to do it in one line.

I know this works to process the whole file:

```
while read p; do echo $p .; done < file.txt
```

I thought the following would work to get the last few lines, but it doesn't. What am I missing?

```
while read p; do echo $p .; done < tail -n 21 file.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `<` redirection expects a file name, not a command. You can use a pipe:

```
tail -n 21 file.txt | while read p; do echo $p .; done
```

Or [process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst) + redirection:

```
while read p; do echo $p .; done < <(tail -n 21 file.txt)
```

Comment: Ah, I was trying to do the second one, but didn't realise I needed an extra `<`. Thanks!

Comment: `<(...)` is its own syntax, called "[process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst)"; it evaluates to the name of a file which, when read, will contain the output from the command `...`. If you want to redirect from that file, then, you need another `<`. That's why the whitespace needs to be exactly the way it is in the answer -- `<< (...)` would be completely different (not a valid process substitution).